# batch to find and copy files to desktop

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy

I've got a few hundred dxf files spread around a server that I need to copy to one folder on my desktop.  Based on other macro's I've written, I tried using the line below, but got an error that it couldn't find the file.  I know from a slow windows explorer search that it exists.  Can anyone help a guy out?  Thanks in advance.

copy s:*\file1.dxf c:\users\me\desktop\DXFs

EDIT:I have a bunch of files in various subfolders on a network drive.  Call them s:\directory1\file1.dxf, s:\directory2\file2.dxf, etc.  I'm looking to write a batch file that would go to my "S" drive and copy file1.dxf from whichever subfolder it happens to be in to a folder on my desktop.  I know the name of each file, just not the location.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line on the current drive, and below the current folder:

```
for /r %a in (*.dxf) do copy "%a" "c:\users\me\desktop\DXFs"
```

Double all `%` to `%%` for batch file use - and the folder must already exist 'o course.

Comment: I don't need to gather all files, just a very specific list of them.  How would I name particular files?

Comment: Perhaps if you edit and put the details in your question then people can focus on what you actually want.